# Issues with adding a variable to python gspread

Tags: python, variables, google-sheets, gspread

I have started to use the [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) library and have sheet already that I'd like to append after the last row that has data in it. I'll retrieve the values between A1 and *maxrows* to loop through them and check if they are empty. However, I am unable to add a variable to the second line here. But perhaps I am just not escaping it correct? I bet this is very simple:

```
maxrows = "A" + str(worksheet.row_count)
cell_list = worksheet.range('A1:A%s') % (maxrows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `maxrows` already is in the form of "An", the concatenation already contains the letter and the number

But you are adding an extra A to it here `worksheet.range('A1:A%s')`

Also you're not using the string interpolation correctly with `%` (in your code you are not applying `%` to the range string)

It should have been one of these

```
maxrows = "A" + str(worksheet.row_count)
worksheet.range('A1:%s' % maxrows)
```

or

```
worksheet.range('A1:A%d' % worksheet.row_count)
```

<sub>(among other possible solutions)</sub>

Comment: Terrific! Thank you for the great explanation of what I did wrong.